# Removing Cisco IOS users with ansible

Tags: ansible, cisco, cisco-ios

I'm trying to use ansible to remove some old users on Cisco IOS switches and routers. The ansible task is currently failing due to the fact that IOS prompts the user on the CLI to confirm if they want to remove the username. Any way around this with ansible?

Here is a CLI example

```
SW01(config)#no username admin
This operation will remove all username related configurations with same name.Do you want to continue? [confirm]
```

ansible task

```
  tasks:
    - name: Remove username
      ios_command:
         commands: no username admin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ios_user` module. Look here for more details: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ios_user_module.html#ios-user-module

Example:

```
- name: Delete a user account
  ios_user:
    name: "neo"
    state: absent
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm!